# How do I make NSUserNotification repeat daily in Mac application?

Tags: objective-c, macos

I want to create daily remind for my Mac application. I've set deliveryRepeatInterval, but it didn't work. It's only create 1 notification.
My code is below:

```
    NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:(NSYearCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSHourCalendarUnit) fromDate:date];
    components.timeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
    [components setDay: components.day + 1];
    [components setHour: 20];
    NSDate *dateToFire = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];

    NSUserNotification *localNotif = [NSUserNotification new];
    localNotif.deliveryRepeatInterval.day = 1;
    localNotif.informativeText = @"Hello";
    localNotif.deliveryTimeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
    localNotif.deliveryDate = dateToFire;

    NSUserNotificationCenter *notiCenter = [NSUserNotificationCenter defaultUserNotificationCenter];
    [notiCenter scheduleNotification:localNotif];
```

Answer (score 1):

I have repaired my code, and it worked.

```
NSDateComponents *repeatTime = [NSDateComponents new];
repeatTime.day = 1;
localNotif.deliveryRepeatInterval = repeatTime;
```